# Restart VMs with PowerCLI .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, vmware, powercli

I have been running into a wall with this one. The goal is to restart VMs utilizing PowerCLI's API with C#. This will be a MVC framework. The user logs in and on the landing page are given a list of servers to restart. Selects server, and restarts one or many of them (checkbox).

My problem is understanding PowerCLI, and what I need. Currently, I have VMware.Vim referenced and that can allow me to connect, get a list of servers. However, I am unsure on how to restart the server via the API. Below are the libraries I installed. I am unsure what else I need other than VMware.Vim to achieve this.

https://code.vmware.com/web/tool/12.0.0/vmware-powercli

I am currently using this youtube video as a [starting point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oLWpoVXEyY). However, any documentation, code examples, or any guidance would be greatly appreciated. This is a bit out of my level, and am completely unfamiliar with PowerCLI.

[More documentation.](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FRestart-VM.html)

Thank you very much for your time,

PowerCLINooby

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i use in .net to restart the VMs. Only library you need is the `VMware.Vim`.

1. First, Get Client thats connected to your vcenter

```
public static VimClient ConnectToVCenter(string vCenterUrl, string username, string password)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

    VimClient client = new VimClientImpl();
    try
    {
        client.Connect($"https://{vCenterUrl}/sdk");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to connect to [{vCenterUrl}]. Exception: [{ex.Message}]");
    }
    client.Login(username, password);
    return client;
}
```

2. Get VM

```
public static VirtualMachine GetVM(VimClient client, string guestVM, ManagedObjectReference parentMoRef = null)
{
    // Lookup VM in vCenter.
    NameValueCollection Filter = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "name", guestVM }
    };

    List<VirtualMachine> virtualMachines = GetEntities<VirtualMachine>(client, parentMoRef, Filter, null);

    // Do some error checking to make sure your VM was found.
    return virtualMachines.FirstOrDefault();
}

// Helper function that can be used to look up various objects like VirtualMachine, Datastore, etc.
public static List<T> GetEntities<T>(VimClient vimClient, ManagedObjectReference beginEntity, NameValueCollection filter, string[] properties)
{
    return vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(T), beginEntity, filter, properties)?.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

3. Power up or down or restart the VM

```
// Use enum for power operations
public enum PowerOp
{
    suspend,
    reset,
    powerOff,
    gracefulOff,
    powerOn,
    powerOnWaitForTools,
    gracefulReboot,
    standby
}

public static void PowerOperation(VimClient client, VirtualMachine vm, PowerOp operation)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case PowerOp.suspend:
            if (vm.Runtime.PowerState != VirtualMachinePowerState.suspended)
                client.WaitForTask(vm.SuspendVM_Task());
            break;

        case PowerOp.reset:
            client.WaitForTask(vm.ResetVM_Task());
            break;

        case PowerOp.powerOff:
            if (vm.Runtime.PowerState != VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOff)
            {
                client.WaitForTask(vm.PowerOffVM_Task());
            }
            break;

        case PowerOp.powerOn:
            if (vm.Runtime.PowerState != VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOn)
            {
                client.WaitForTask(vm.PowerOnVM_Task(vm.Runtime.Host));
            }
            break;

        case PowerOp.powerOnWaitForTools:
            if (vm.Runtime.PowerState != VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOn)
            {
                client.WaitForTask(vm.PowerOnVM_Task(vm.Runtime.Host));
            }
            vm.WaitForTools(client);
            break;

        case PowerOp.gracefulReboot:
            vm.RebootGuest();
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // Wait at least 10 seconds to let the server start with reboot.
            vm.WaitForTools(client);
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Just a precaution.
            break;

        case PowerOp.gracefulOff:
            if (vm.Runtime.PowerState != VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOff)
                vm.ShutdownGuest();
            vm.WaitForPowerState(client, VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOff);
            break;

        case PowerOp.standby:
            vm.StandbyGuest();
            break;

        default:
            throw new ApplicationException($"Error: Unknown power operation requested");
    }
}
```